# Slicing / cutting bodies in box2d in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d, cocos2d-x-2.x

i am currently working on a project which is having use of box2d and cocos2dx framework.Now i have requirement to slice the box2d body as user cut the body using mouse or swipe.Box2d body should be cut in 2 parts and also sprite should also sliced as user swiped.for example you can take fruit ninja where fruits sliced in 2 parts.how would i achive this.

Answer (score -1):

In fruit Ninja I think sprites are cut and not bodies. Still bodies can be cut into two halves as tought in this Ray's Tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14439/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-3

All you need to do is convert this code into cpp code and BANG you are done :)